# Cartoon similar to Transformers, with two gangs, good and bad

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I was born in 90's, and I used to watch Cartoon Network.  I have been trying to identify a show for the past 3 years, but I have not yet found it.  It was a bit like a Transformers style, but not fully.

There were two gangs, good and bad. In the good gang there was a queen, and a few youngsters would be protecting her. They traveled in space, and the queen's protectors had their own robots.

When a problem came they moved inside of the robots and operated them. After some shows one protector got a powerful knife and if he showed that knife to the sky, the robot will come from up there and would be fixed around his body.  Later, the queen's husband joined the enemy team to fight.

Can someone identify this show?

Comment: How sure are you about the robots?  Fights in the sky, princess protected by youngsters, and "fixed around his body" make me think it might be the Japanese anime series "Saint Seiya", (1986), also titled "Knights of the Zodiac" for the English dubbed version.  The princess was the reincarnation of the goddess Athena.  Each of her protectors, or "saints", had magical armor, (not robots), that would attach itself to his body when it was called.  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0161952/

Comment: but i wr 90's kid in that years where mentioned bt 86-89

Comment: no am sure the line is correct princess will be protected her husband or some one frm the good gang will become enemy later

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe it's [Mobile Suit Gundam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Suit_Gundam), First Gundam, Gundam 0079, or simply Gundam '79

[image: Mobile Suit Gundam]

It had Queen, Kingdom, Federation, and the plane can be transformed into large robot.

Comment: I'm not aware of the original Gundam being aired on Cartoon Network

Comment: Just my guess based on the description above. Maybe it was never aired on Cartoon Network. :D

Comment: @bayuah i think you are near but i want to conform it whether it is the same what am searching.. i am feeling this could be that one

Comment: Some Mobile Suit has a sword used to attack and defend. And the Mobile Suit of main male character has a big white sword.

Comment: man you are just awesome thank you so much !! actually it is aired in the name of gundam wing any way thanks for the help

Comment: Please give a check mark, if this question has been answered. :D

Answer (score 5):

Are you talking about the [Lion Force Voltron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltron#Lion_Force_Voltron_.28Voltron_of_the_Far_Universe.29)?

[image]

It had a princess, but not a queen (I think one of the Voltron series had the queen appear as a spirit).  There was a blazing sword and katana, if that's what you mean by a "knife".

Comment: i cant able to find the series you said there s a queen which series that is

Comment: no not this it will be even more stylish fights will be happen in sky there will be princess who have some protectors

Comment: I can't remember if it is that particular series or not...